# How to change the content view after a certain time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to change my content view from the Layout XML file to a GamePanel class after a certain time!
i'm using a Handler to do it but i'm getting an error under `this`
`new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
                Sound1.release();
                Sound2.start();
            }
        }, 5000);`
and it's telling me to change 1st parameter of method 'GamePanel' from Context to Runnable, But i don't want to do that!!

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to **className**.this

where **className** is your activity or Fragment name

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
 setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
            Sound1.release();
            Sound2.start();
}
}, 5000);
```